# My <section> is in the top of my <nav>, as far as I know <nav> is in top of <section>

Tags: html, css

SO my `<section>` appears in te top of the `<nav>`, let say it will text wrap the `<nav>` section. How will I put the `<section>` below the `<nav>`

It gives me problem every time i put some text in  and the text will appear behind the nav

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

header,
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {}

aside {
  float: left;
}

aside.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="mf.png" alt="Mandaue Foam" align="left" style="width:180px;height:108.56px;">
  <div style="text-align: right;">Search: <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search Here"></br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;">AF No. : <input type="text" name="AF No." placeholder="AF No."></br>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;">Asset No. : <input type="text" name="AF No." placeholder="Asset No."></div>
  <div style="text-align: center; text"><strong> ACCOUNTABILITY FORM <strong></div>
     </br>
    </header>
    <nav>
     <div style='position:fixed;top:230px;left:100px;'><input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For Official Use </br></br>
     <input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For use in showroom to be returned on <input type ="date"></br></br>
     <input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For use in showroom not to be returned
     <div style='position:fixed;top:230px;right:150px;'><input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> For sample</br></br><div>
     <input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress5" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> On Loan </br></br>
     <input type="radio" name="progress" id="progress6" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)"> Other <input type="text" name="progress" id="progress6" placeholder="State the Purpose">
    </nav>
    <section>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your HTML is invalid. Please validate and correct your errors first. For example, `<strong>` cannot contain the elements it has.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is invalid. please check again, and that's what causes your  above .

please look at jsfiddle for the full code.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLbmc6z9/

```
<header>
 <div>
  <img src="mf.png" alt="Mandaue Foam" align="left">
 </div>
</header>
```